# Can Bluestacks handle dynamic textures?

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-emulator, textures

Can Bluestacks (latest, API level 15 max) handle dynamic textures (textures you can render to on the fly)?

The following program is supposed to use a dynamic texture:

http://blog.shayanjaved.com/2011/05/13/android-opengl-es-2-0-render-to-texture/

When I import the project containing the above program (the link to the source code is on the above page) into Eclipse and run it on my Bluestacks (version 0.8.11, released June 22, 2014, Android version 4.0.4), all I see is a black screen.

I don't know if the program is device-dependent and Bluestacks simply does not process dynamic textures.

I know my Bluestacks can handle textures as big as 512 x 512 (at least), but changing the example program's dynamic texture's size to 512 x 512 doesn't help.

It would be nice if somebody could try to run this program on his/her physical Android device/s and/or Bluestacks and post the result.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Bluestacks (version 0.8.11, released June 22, 2014, Android version 4.0.4) can process at least one dynamic texture.

I changed a few lines of the example program I downloaded and it showed something. I have no idea if what I saw was what the author of the program intended, so I adapted the part of the code dealing with what I believed to be a dynamic texture and my program works now. I tested a dynamic texture as big as 1600 x 798, and it worked.